# Get original size bitmap from drawable

Tags: android, database, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

I tried to get full size bitmap from drawable but not get.My image store into drawable folder and its sized 1082*1673 and when i get bitmap from drawable its sized 662*1024

I tried to all possible changes

My code shown below

```
[1] Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.t_0001);

[2] BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.t_0001, o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put that image must be in drawable-xxhdpi folder

Comment: Thanks.. But my image work on all device so how to possible?

Comment: You have to make different size of your image and put into several folders like drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xxhdpi etc.But first check with only drawable-xxhdpi it works with all possible devices

Comment: Not work i seen into logcat but maximum 1024*1024 bitmap get how to solve please help me

Comment: Check with different devices. I think i should work.

Comment: Sorry, Not get but my images used to generally color fill app if my images stretch then i could not fill color into images

Answer (score -1):

I guess if you put your images under the Assets folder (or subfolder inside assets), the auto resize will not happen.